# React Big Calendar hi-light current day in Month view

Tags: css, reactjs, react-big-calendar

My requirement is so simple but could not find a way to do that. The only thing I need to do is hi-light as the below image.

Lets assume today is 09th April 2015 so it is Thursday,

So I need to hi-light Thursday background in red colour and 09th Cell border in red colour.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use reference from below code.

First you need to import

```
import withDragAndDrop from "react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop";
```

Then call BigCalendar like this:

```
BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment);
const DragAndDropCalendar = withDragAndDrop(BigCalendar);
```

Finally, Render the view as below lines of code:

```
render() {
return (
  <DragAndDropCalendar
    selectable
    events={this.state.events}
    onEventDrop={this.moveEvent}
    resizable
    onEventResize={this.resizeEvent}
  />
);
```

You can take reference from this link: [Big calendar tool](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-big-calendar-drag-and-drop-events-between-months-forked-q9ymvm?file=/src/index.js:1244-1460)

Your output look as similar as attached screenshot[image: BigCalendar_Image]

Comment: So @Khushbu kadia how to apply CSS (hi-light) Date & Day as per the screenshot with use of drag and drop? I do not see those are hi-lighted in your screenshot

Comment: @mapmalith You can do like this: 
`<BigCalendar

  // other props here

  eventPropGetter={
    (event, start, end, isSelected) => {
      let newStyle = {
        backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
        color: 'black',
        borderRadius: "0px",
        border: "none"
      };

      if (event.isMine){
        newStyle.backgroundColor = "lightgreen"
      }

      return {
        className: "",
        style: newStyle
      };
    }
  }
/>` Sorry for the format, but you can set after copying it.

Comment: According to the documentation `eventPropGetter ` -  **Optionally provide a function that returns an object of className or style props to be applied to the the event node.**